# Javascript addEventListener only add a class to one element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a tab-like system where when you click a tab, it removes the classes from other tabs and adds them to the clicked class

heres the code

JS:

```
const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('Tab');

for (let tab=0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){
  tabs[tab].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    for (let tab=0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){
      e.target.classList.remove('active-tab')
    }
    e.target.classList.add('active-tab')
  })
}
```

css:

```
.active-tab {
  border-bottom: 10px solid pink;
}
```

It is actually adding the class and adding a pink underline, but it doesn't remove the other classes, so all the tabs can have the underline

Example:

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrImq.png)

Comment: In your for loop you need to use `tab.classList.remove('active-tab')`

Comment: I think it removes it, but it doesn't add the class if I do that.

Comment: Create a separate function where you loop through all the elements and remove the required class you want to add later. Then in the event listener run that function first and then add the class to the target element.

Comment: And you should use event delegation.

Comment: Sorry, you need `tabs[tab].classList.remove('active-tab')` (I always iterate over the elements)

Comment: What is event delegation, im sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Basically adding _one_ listener to a parent element that catches events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. In the handler you would check that the child that fired the event was the one you wanted (`if (e.target.matches('.tab')) {...}` for example), and then remove/add the classes etc if the condition passes.

Comment: It works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wy7x4sad/

Comment: I will also probably put it in a different function to clean it up Ali Mustafa

Comment: Note if those tabs are part of a navigation system you may want to add them as a list within [a `nav` element](https://jsfiddle.net/6z2nLsdu/). @dumpsterfire997

Comment: Yeah i already did @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason it is not removing any of the classes is because you are using `e.target.classList.remove('active-tab')` which removes the class from the element/tab that was clicked. You are looping through the elements/tabs, but not actually selecting any of them.

So you would want to use something like `tabs[tab].classList.remove('active-tab')` instead.

```
const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('Tab');

for (let tab=0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){
  tabs[tab].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    for (let tab=0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){
      tabs[tab].classList.remove('active-tab')
    }
    e.target.classList.add('active-tab')
  })
}
```

For the sake of avoiding `for` loops with list of elements/arrays, here is alternative way to do this same thing

```
document.querySelectorAll('.Tab').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
        document.querySelectorAll("active-tab").forEach(t => {
            t.classList.remove("active-tab");
        });
        e.target.classList.add("active-tab");
    });
});
```

Comment: This Works, i will definitely try the second method

Comment: Only thing i had to change was to change "tabs[tab].classList.remove('active-tab')" to "tabs[tab].firstChild.classList.remove('active-tab')"

Comment: @dumpsterfire997 For future posts, be sure to include things like your HTML/CSS as well. Because no HTML was posted I had no way of knowing how your elements/classes were set up so my answer does not use the `.firstChild` property.

Comment: Oh i loaded all my html with javascript so i thought it would be to confusing to read it